# Breadcrumblist last item error from Structured Data Testing Tool: "A value for the item field is required."

Tags: html, schema.org, breadcrumbs, rdfa

We are using RDFa format to display the breadcrumb using the examples provided by [`BreadcrumbList`](https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList). When we insert the following example into [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool), we get the following errors.

Setup:

1. Display all `item`s in the `BreadcrumbList`.
2. Last `item` in the breadcrumb is displayed in plain text.

**What is the correct format for the last `item` when using RDFa format?**

#### Sample code

```html
<ol vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="BreadcrumbList">
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
    <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="https://example.com/dresses">
     <span property="name">Dresses</span></a>
     <meta property="position" content="1">
  </li>
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
    <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="https://example.com/foo-bar">
     <span property="name">foo-bar</span></a>
     <meta property="position" content="2">
  </li>
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
    <span property="name">Real Dresses</span>
    <meta property="position" content="3">
  </li>
</ol>
```

Error Message for the last item using code from above:

> A value for the item field is required.

#### What we tried but did not validate

```html
<ol vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="BreadcrumbList">
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
    <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="https://example.com/dresses">
      <span property="name">Dresses</span></a>
    <meta property="position" content="1">
  </li>
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
    <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="https://example.com/foo-bar">
      <span property="name">foo-bar</span></a>
    <meta property="position" content="2">
  </li>
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
    <div property="item">
      <span property="name">Real Dresses</span>
    </div>
    <meta property="position" content="3">
  </li>
</ol>
```

Error Message when using `<div property="item">` from above:

> The value provided for item.id must be a valid URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last item (for the current page) still represents a web page, even if you don’t want to show a hyperlink.

So, simply add `typeof="WebPage"` to the `div` of the last item:

```html
<div property="item" typeof="WebPage">
```

You could still provide the last item’s URI (without showing it) by using the `resource` attribute:

```
<div property="item" typeof="WebPage" resource="https://example.com/real-dresses">
```

This results in:

```html
    <ol vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="BreadcrumbList">

      <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
        <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="https://example.com/dresses">
          <span property="name">Dresses</span></a>
        <meta property="position" content="1">
      </li>

      <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
        <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="https://example.com/foo-bar">
          <span property="name">foo-bar</span></a>
        <meta property="position" content="2">
      </li>

      <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
        <div property="item" typeof="WebPage" resource="https://example.com/real-dresses">
          <span property="name">Real Dresses</span>
        </div>
        <meta property="position" content="3">
      </li>

    </ol>
```

Comment: changing `href` to `resource` using the `<div>` element did the job and is also validating in the Structured Data tool.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue on my local project:

```
<a href="http://localhost:4356/dresses" itemprop="item">
<span itemprop="name">dresses</span>
<meta itemprop="position" content="2">
</a>
```

was throwing error: **A value for the item field is required.**

for me, it is resolved by providing a valid URL for itemprop :

```
<a href="https://example.com/dresses" itemprop="item">
<span itemprop="name">dresses</span>
<meta itemprop="position" content="2">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears when you don't want to make last element of the breadcrumbs a hyperlink, which in most of cases is just a link to the page itself. In this case to avoid errors from Google's Structured Data Testing Tool you are free to use [json-ld](https://json-ld.org/) as well.

**HTML**

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <a href="https://example.com/dresses">
      <span>Dresses</span></a>      
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://example.com/foo-bar">
      <span>foo-bar</span></a>      
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span>Real Dresses</span>
    </div>      
  </li>
</ol>
```

**JSON+LD**

```js
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/", 
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList", 
  "itemListElement": [{
    "@type": "ListItem", 
    "position": 1, 
    "name": "Dresses",
    "item": "https://example.com/dresses"  
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem", 
    "position": 2, 
    "name": "foo-bar",
    "item": "https://example.com/foo-bar"  
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem", 
    "position": 3, 
    "name": "Real Dresses",
    "item": "https://example.com/real-dresses"  
  }]
}
</script>
```